# Spring Application Context - Main and Test Folders

Tags: java, spring, junit, applicationcontext

I have a Spring project with 4 typical source folders - `main/src`, `main/resources`, `test/src` and `test/resources`. When I run my application, Spring fetches the application-context file in `main/resources` and if I run any Junit test, it fetches the `application-context.xml` file under `test/resources`. How does Spring fetch the `application-context.xml` file appropriately or is there any config involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running any other project with `jsf` or with `Struts`, they will also pick resources from respective folders. It has nothing to do with spring. It will be taken care by maven or any other build system you are using.

```
main/src , main/resources , test/src , test/resources
```

these folders are standard when you create maven or gradle project.

Comment: I am not running a maven build but rather running the junit from eclipse. Is  Maven taking care of this behind the scenes? This was an already existing application hence wanted to check if I need to do any configuration achieving this behavior when I create a new project.

Comment: @PunterVicky When you run your `junit` your `junit` library will always look for the resources in test folder, because when you run your test as  `Run as-> Junit` your ide will use junit from the classpath to run your test. and `Junit` will pick resources from test folders

Comment: @Punter: This doesn't address the question of how the test chooses between context xml under src/test/resources and src/main/resources.  Obviously the test still needs things under src/main.

Answer (score 1):

The application tells Spring where the application context is. Web applications do this by configuring a ContextLoaderListener in the web.xml.
For each test how your application context gets loaded is part of the test's configuration, the @ContextConfiguration annotation specifies how the context gets loaded from what location or from what annotated classes.

For instance if I set up the test to use

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
classes = MyTest.ContextConfiguration.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired MyStuff stuff;

    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean public MyStuff getMyStuff() {
            return new MyStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

then MyTest uses the annotations in the test to decide what to inject into, and populates those fields using the specified ContextConfiguration. It totally disregards any xml configuration in the classpath.

The context loader can also specify locations to load the context from, see the documentation for [org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextLoader.html).

You don't say what version of Spring you're using. Prior to 3.0 tests managed test contexts by implementing the abstract method loadContext of the class org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests, which was part of the hierarchy that spring-aware tests extended.

Comment: I think it was about how junit will pick appropriate resources, I.e when u place a resource in test resources folder and in src resource folder. Yes we will specify class path of config file, but how does it find it from test instead of source

Comment: And also try taking any stand alone maven project with out spring frame work. And include some resource in both test resources and src resources, include junit in your cp and write a test class that use this resource and run test to see which resource junit is picking

Comment: @Pragnini: the specific question was how the test chooses which application context to use. spring doesn't leave it up to whatever's on the classpath given by maven or the IDE.

Comment: I think if I understand clearly he has mentioned he has two config files, one in src folder and one in test folder with ( same name), as he already running test means his test Chad might have specified context config location in the above @ContextConfiguration with location attribute, so I have provided that answer, how junit picking resource from test folder

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but with Spring-boot 2.x the folder structure is different.
This is what I get from Spring initializer and IntelliJ:

[image]